efficient R code to assign timestamp (vintage) to each row in a dataframe, based on related rows in the same dataframe
I have a dataset of customer transactions, and need to create a new column (Vintage), based on a fairly complicated set of 'temporal' rules:

in a nutshell, the requirement is to tag each entry (row) by the Date the Name came on book (i.e. when were they a “NEW” 'Movement'). In practice, there are several situations to consider:

if the name first appeared in the dataset with 'EXISTING' tag, then Vintage = 'Back Book'

if for the same name there is a 'NEW' tag at a later reporting date - Vintage becomes the Date of the 'NEW' entry

for 'EXISTING' entries following a 'NEW' tag - Vintage = the most recent 'NEW' entry Date

if there is a new 'NEW' entry for the name, the Vintage value becomes the Date of the new 'NEW' entry


This might sound quite convoluted, so I have included the image below to illustrate the desired outcome under all possible scenarios:

code to recreate the toy dataset:
structure(list(Date = c(20240430L, 20240531L, 20240630L, 20240229L, 
20240331L, 20240531L, 20240630L, 20240731L, 20230930L, 20231031L, 
20231231L, 20230930L, 20231031L, 20231231L, 20240531L, 20240731L
), Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    Movement = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("EXISTING", "NEW"
    ), class = "factor"), Vintage = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("20230930", 
    "20231231", "20240531", "20240731", "Back Book"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

I am looking for a code which can create the 'Vintage' column in an efficient manner, as the dataset has over 100k entries and keeps growing. Thanks!
I have tried creating two copies of the dataset (df_A, df_B), and looking up the Vintage for each row from df_A into df_B, using rowwise(), mutate() and a custom 'assignVintage' function called from within mutate(), however the code only performs subset of the required temporal rules and despite that is still very inefficient, running for over 20minutes - hence why I am looking for a more elegant solution (if one exist).

Here is a solution.

Create an auxiliary column telling if it's the beginning of a group where Movement is "NEW";
if it isn't because the groups haven't started yet, assign "Back Book", if it is and it's the group's first element, assign the date, else assign NA;
fill the NA's with the previous value.

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

df1 %>%
  mutate(new = cumsum(Movement == "NEW"), .by = Name) %>%
  mutate(
    Vintage2 = case_when(
      new == 0 ~ "Back Book", 
      new > 0 & Movement == "NEW" ~ as.character(Date),
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    ), 
    .by = new
  ) %>%
  tidyr::fill(Vintage2) %>%
  select(-new)
#>        Date Name Movement   Vintage  Vintage2
#> 1  20240430    A EXISTING Back Book Back Book
#> 2  20240531    A EXISTING Back Book Back Book
#> 3  20240630    A EXISTING Back Book Back Book
#> 4  20240229    B EXISTING Back Book Back Book
#> 5  20240331    B EXISTING Back Book Back Book
#> 6  20240531    B      NEW  20240531  20240531
#> 7  20240630    B EXISTING  20240531  20240531
#> 8  20240731    B EXISTING  20240531  20240531
#> 9  20230930    C      NEW  20230930  20230930
#> 10 20231031    C EXISTING  20230930  20230930
#> 11 20231231    C EXISTING  20230930  20230930
#> 12 20230930    D EXISTING Back Book Back Book
#> 13 20231031    D EXISTING Back Book Back Book
#> 14 20231231    D      NEW  20231231  20231231
#> 15 20240531    D EXISTING  20231231  20231231
#> 16 20240731    D      NEW  20240731  20240731

Created on 2024-08-21 with reprex v2.1.0

thank you sir. I was initially getting a different result running your code, but managed to make your code work after upgrading R to the latest version on my personal laptop.
turned out older R versions treat the '.by' argument of mutate() differently and instead of using in the intended manner, it created a new '.by' column in the dataset  and some of the Vintage2 values were different:
vintage pic
if anyone knows how to make this code work on old versions of R (<2022), it would be much appreciated as my work doesn't allow R upgrades!

UPDATE: I only needed to upgrade 'dplyr' package to the latest version to make it work, which I was able to do on my work setup despite all the corporate restrictions. thanks again for this efficient piece of code!

@Ondrej Yes, as long as dplyr can be installed in your version of R, the code will run. If you read the documentation help("mutate"), the new argument .by is tagged Experimental, it is a recent one.
